# How to get a special list of dates in every month in a given range using moment.js

Tags: javascript, date, momentjs

Let's assume start date is `2019-01-10`. We have to check 15 months ahead. 
So the end date is `2020-04-10`.

I want to get a list of every 10th of the day in each month in the above list.

Like following :

> ['2019-01-10' , '2019-02-10' , '2019-03-10' , '2019-04-10' , ...... ,
>   '2020-04-10' ]

How can I do this in moment,js ?
If this is not possible in moment.js, what are the ways we can do this in JavaScript ?

Comment: What if the date is January 31st? There is not 31st in Feb, April, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can move date by `n` months via [**add**](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/manipulating/add/) method. Something like this:

```js
function dateOffsetByMonths(months, dateStr, format) {
  var startDate = moment(dateStr, format);
  return Array.from(Array(months + 1).keys()).reduce(function(res, n, i) {
    var date = startDate.clone();
    date.add(i, 'months');
    res.push(date.format('YYYY-MM-DD'));
    return res;
  }, []);
}

console.log(dateOffsetByMonths(15, '2019-01-10', 'YYYY-MM-DD'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.23.0/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: It may be better on each loop to copy the original date and add *n* months, otherwise start dates like 31 Jan will reduce to 28 or 29 Feb, then continue on the 28/29th of each month. If the original date is cloned, and the start is 31 Jan, you should instead get the last day of each month (at least that's what I understand the OP wants). ;-)

Comment: @RobG good point! Now when using `clone()` the code will also cover the end of month cases

Answer (score 2):

In vanilla JavaScript just use [`Date.setMonth`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/setMonth). For starting dates such as 29, 30 and 31 the resulting dates will roll over into next month so you must handle that case.

```js
function buildDates(startDate, months) {
  return Array.from({
    length: months
  }, function(_, i) {
    var date = new Date(startDate.getTime());
    var mnth = date.getMonth();
    date.setMonth(mnth + i);
    if (date.getMonth() !== (mnth + i) % 12) {
      date.setDate(0);
    }
    return date;
  });
}

console.log(buildDates(new Date(2019, 0, 10), 15));
console.log(buildDates(new Date(2019, 0, 31), 15));
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `array#from` to accumulate all dates in an array. Keep adding the index to the initial date in each iteration.

```js
function allDates(length, date, format) {
  return Array.from({length}, (_, i) => moment(date, format).add(i, 'months').format(format));
}

console.log(allDates(15, '2019-01-31', 'YYYY-MM-DD'));
console.log(allDates(15, '2019-01-10', 'YYYY-MM-DD'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.23.0/moment.min.js"></script>
```